# The listener runs again every time the widget rebuild

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i want to listen if there is a constant change in my firestore db. But it runs when widget rebuild (idk 
because of init state? but why listener dont prevent the fonc?)

```
class _ActivityScreen extends State<ActivityScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();

  @override 
  void initState(){
    super.initState();

    checkFocChanges();    
  }

  checkFocChanges() async {
    var reference = Firestore.instance.collection('etkinlikler').orderBy('sıra');
    reference.snapshots().listen((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.documentChanges.forEach((change) {
        resetDb(change.document.data);                    
      });
    });
  }
  void resetDb(documents){
    print(documents['ad'].toString());}
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return BlocProvider(
        builder:(BuildContext context ) => ActivitiesBloc(),
```

I really need help between the firestore and the flutter.

Comment: Where are you updating the state? We may need more code to find the issue?

Comment: I edited the code,I don't call the checkfocchanges from anywhere else.ok as a newbie i wanna make if firestore documents changed refresh my local db (which same with firestore) i coded local db (bloc and sembast) now i need just listen change firestore :/ I spent all day please

Comment: 1) How you want to get the updates, when they happen or when you load the app?